# Why is changing the virtual host server name and local domain name in /etc/hosts to *.dev forcing a redirect to HTTPS?

Tags: apache-http-server

I have set up a basic Vagrant box with Ubuntu 18.04 and Apache2 installed with very little changed from the defaults and recommended settings.

In the virtual host .conf file in the guest machine I have only added the ServerName as wordpress.dev and in the /etc/hosts file on the host machine added a line to resolve wordpress.dev to 127.0.0.1. The Vagrant file has port 4567 on the host forwarding to port 80 on the guest as described in the Vagrant manual. All fairly typical stuff and has worked before for me on other local or guest machine sites without any problems.

However, in this case, when I try to browse the non-secure http://wordpress.dev:4567 on the host machine the browser always redirects to the secure http**s**://wordpress.dev:4567. Naturally, the site cannot load because I don't have a SSL certificate. It does this whichever browser I use.

If I change the .conf and /etc/hosts files to use "wordpress" instead of "wordpress.dev" but keep everything else exactly the same, reload Apache, then I *can* browse http://wordpress:4567 without being redirected to https. When I change it back I have the same problem again.

This makes no sense to me. Why is adding ".dev" making any difference to whether or not the browser forces me onto HTTPS?

I've cleared caches and tried using private browsing and it makes no difference.

There is probably a very obvious reason why this is happening but I cannot see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is adding `.dev` making any difference as to whether or not the browser forces me onto HTTPS?

Chrome 63+ (December 2017) and Firefox 61+ (June 2018) [force all domains ending in `.dev` to be redirected to HTTPS](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/) via a preloaded (in-browser) [HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) header.

Furthermore, [Google now officially maintains the `.dev` domain as a live gTLD](https://www.blog.google/technology/developers/hello-dev/) and began registering `.dev` addresses in February 2019. [They highlight the fact that `.dev` domains only use HTTPS as a selling point](https://security.googleblog.com/2017/09/broadening-hsts-to-secure-more-of-web.html).

In the past it was possible to disable HSTS manually but, as far as I am aware, that flag has been removed.